# Regex for "strings of equal number of a's and b's that beginns with an a and ending with b."r

Tags: regex

I am trying to find regex for "strings of equal number of a's and b's that beginns with an a and ending with b."

Here is what i've done : https://regex101.com/r/6sEGqm/1/

Comment: Do you wish the regex to match the string if and only if the string begins with an `a`, ends with a `b` and contains equal numbers of those two letters? Can the string contain characters other than `a` and `b` (e.g. `abcdaaebfb`)? If the answer to the first question is “yes”, prepare to be disappointed as no regex can enforce the third condition.

Comment: Please, show some test cases, with strings that should match and some that shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to cover case like `abbaab` then here you go:

```
/^(?:ab)+?$/
```

Comment: This only works if `'a'` and `'b'` are alternating, yet the OP's test string at the link is `"ababba"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland a quote from op's question: "and ending with b."

Comment: Good point, which leaves me a bit mystified, but there's still no suggestion that `a` and `b` are alternating.